# How to assign the time for $cordovaLocaNotification using ion-datetime-picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to develop my first app in which i want to assign the user assigned time as 7:10 pm, which is used to repeat daily but not able to assign its value to attribute date in $cordovaLocalNotification. And one more thing its better to get me those values from the database as i am using $cordovaSQLite Plugin to store data.

Here is my code for storing,

```
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, $scope.medicine.medicinename,$scope.medicine.medicinetype,$scope.medicine.timeValue1])
```

assigning the value,

```
  $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
          id:$scope.medicine._id,
        title: $scope.medicine.medicinename,
        message: $scope.medicine.medicinetype,
        repeat:'daily',
        date: $scope.medicine.timeValue1
      })
      $ionicPopup.alert({
                title:"Done",
                template:"Notification set for daily"+$scope.medicine.timeValue1
            })
```

Values are storing but not able to work with localnotification. If any example for dynamic assigning of values which show the notification will be great help.

Comment: Instead of using repeat and date, better to use, every and at attribute think will work for you

Comment: Thanks @ANK, I tried that but the same problem.